# How to enable Horizontal Pager to show Offscreen page Using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm familiar with `Jetpack Compose` And Trying to Get `Horizontal Pager` Like Below. But Not able to get the exact look and feel.

I have tried setting `PageSize`, `ContentPaddings`, `CustomOffset`, etc But Did not works.

Current Output.
[image: current]

Expected Output.
[image: expected]

My Current Code:

```
@Composable
fun LoadingScreen() {

    val state = rememberPagerState { 3 }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = AppColor)
            .padding(12.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = state,
            beyondBoundsPageCount = 2,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {page->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(240.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                        .background(
                            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                                listOf(
                                    Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                    Color(0x00FFFFFF)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        ,
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rafiki),
                        contentDescription = "Slider"
                    )
                }
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                    text = "FOOD",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.NormalText.copy(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding content padding in horizontal pager should do the work for you: `contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 40.dp)`

Comment: And for achieving scaling animation while sliding, you can add `graphicsLayer` modifier and update `scaleY` on the basis of `currentPageOffset` and `currentPage`

Comment: I have tried these ways but not getting desired output

Comment: I want left and right items to visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the content padding and item spacing as you wish

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerDemo3(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        val itemSpacing = 16.dp
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
            10
        })

        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = modifier,
            state = pagerState,
            flingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
                state = pagerState,
                pagerSnapDistance = PagerSnapDistance.atMost(0)
            ),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 32.dp),
            pageSpacing = itemSpacing
        ) { page ->
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(300.dp)
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                        indication = null,
                        enabled = true,
                    ) {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page)
                        }
                    }.graphicsLayer {
                        val pageOffSet = (
                                (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState
                                    .currentPageOffsetFraction
                                ).absoluteValue
                        alpha = lerp(
                            start = 0.5f,
                            stop = 1f,
                            fraction = 1f - pageOffSet.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                        )
                        scaleY =   lerp(
                            start = 0.75f,
                            stop = 1f,
                            fraction = 1f - pageOffSet.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                        )
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the content padding is how much of the padding is required on the sides. the item spacing is spacing between items. you would need to tweak these appropriately. The rest of the scaling and alpha can be done in graphics layer